# react native save file to internal memory

Tags: javascript, android, file, react-native

I have to save a text file in the main internal memory.
I'm using `react-native-fs`, none of the Constants, it's allowing me to do this.

How can I do?
Can you recommend other `libraries` that allow you to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure about `react-native-fs`. But you can use [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) which worked fine for me

I believe this is the best package among all packages for downloading files from `react-native` that supports both `android` and `IOS`

**Updated Answer:**

import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob '

path: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir/"File name";

In the above line `DownloadDir` means `Downloads` folder in the internal storage which is nothing but `/storage/emulated/0/Download`

if you want to store some other folders you can have a look at available [directories](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#dirs)

Comment: It seems that fs do not let me write about path: / storage / emulated / 0 /
By chance react-native-fetch-blob allows it?
I need to create a file and write to it, but in the path / storage / emulated / 0 /.

Comment: I have a .doc file. How can i save this in my react-native project and then need to download the same file by hitting the download button. Here i don't want to view or do anything. Just I need to show a download button and if the user click download i need to download the file

Comment: @sejn 

` return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          RNFetchBlob.config({
            fileCache: true,
            appendExt: ext
          }).fetch('GET', documentUrl)
          .then(res => {
            //   console.log('The file saved to ', res.path());
              const downloadFile = Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file://' + res.path() : '' + res.path();
            console.log('downloadFile ', downloadFile);
              resolve(true);
            }).catch(err => {
              reject(err)
            })
        }); `